# Copy/move group files with renaming

Tags: bash, cp, file-copy, mv

I want to copy (or move) some files like `cp ./patt*.py /other/path`. However `/other/path/` already contents files with the same names. So, I would like copy with renaming (adding some suffix, for example):

```
./pattfoo.py - copy to - /other/path/pattfoo.py_other
./pattbar.py - copy to - /other/path/pattbar.py_other
./pattfur.py - copy to - /other/path/pattfur.py_other
etc.
```

What is the simplest way to complete the task?

Comment: rename first and then copy

Comment: @Anthon That's certainly not the simplest way.

Answer (score 2):

```
rsync -v --backup --suffix=something ./patt*.py /other/path
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cd <old_path>
rename "s/.py/.py.rename/" *.py
mv *.py.rename <new_path>
```

Comment: What if `foo.py` exists in `<old_path>` and `foo.py.rename` exists in `<new_path>`?

Comment: @Gilles: You might as well post that comment on the question — the OP seems to assume that he (or she) can copy (or move) `./foo.py` to `/other/path/foo.py_other` without collision.  Perhaps the more interesting question is "What if `foo.py` and `foo.py.rename` both exist in `<old_path>`?"